# React Native mobile app authentication using google and facebook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am completely lost, with even what to look at. However, I am creating my first react native application. In this app I wish to allow the user to authenticate with Google as well as Facebook.

My Issue is: User logs in using google auth. They then log out and re-authenticate with facebook. However they have already logged in before and under this second auth I wish them to connect back to the same account.

Could someone please help me, is there a way to do this, I am lost. I need direction on this so appreciate all/any help given.

Any further questions on this. I will do my best to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has more to do with persisting data and keeping duplicates out. When you do authentication you habe to store some kind of universal ID like the users email and Google/Facebook IDs. When a user logs in with whichever account you can identify them and match the correct profile.

Lets say the user has different emails with facebook and google, you might tell him after auth with google, that a User will be created newly on your app with the given data. At this point users can realize thats not what they expected, as they have already an account and retry with facebook.